# Did any group in the UK oppose Falklands war?

Tags: united-kingdom

Did any group in the UK oppose Falklands war?

If Yes,

- Were they political groups or non-political/human-rights groups?
- What was their rationale/objective?
- did they gain any public support?
- Were they arrested?

Comment: Do you mean only opposing the military action around the Falklands in general, or do you include opposing specific actions?

Comment: @origimbo, the 1st one.

Comment: War *always* has opponents.

Comment: I strongly recommend you watch the film [This is England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_England). And listen to some Toots and the Maytals every once in a while.

Comment: The vast majority of British people opposed the war. Or do you mean, "Did any oppose Britain fighting back?"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

On the [3rd April 1982](https://api.parliament.uk/historic-hansard/commons/1982/apr/03/falkland-islands), at the time of the onset of formal conflict in the area of the Falkland Islands (or to the Argentinians, the Malvinas) [Margaret Thatcher's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Thatcher) Conservative government obtained the support of [Michael Foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Foot) (the leader of the opposition Labour party), as well as the [SDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Democratic_Party_(UK)), its centrist breakaway offshoot, and the third largest parliamentary party. This meant there was no mainstream opposition within Westminster.

This didn't mean, however, that the idea of a conflict in the South Atlantic was universally popular with MPs, either on the [left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tam_Dalyell), or the [right](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/politics/margaret-thatcher/9947164/Kenneth-Clarke-opposed-fighting-Argentina-over-Falklands-Thatcher-papers-show.html) of the House. Opposition ranged from conscientious objection to war, to a realisation of the large potential economic, human and political downsides of a failed military campaign.

Outside of Westminster, opposition to Mrs. Thatcher's policies came primarily from her natural opponents on the [political left](http://www.socialismtoday.org/108/falklands.html), either objecting to [war in general](http://www.ppu.org.uk/falklands/falklands5.html), or to a war with strong perceived colonial overtones. Human rights as such doesn't seem initially to have been a primary general motive, since the Argentinian soldiers were military invaders, who had interned the residents of the islands. This changed to some extent with the [sinking of the light cruiser General Belgrano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARA_General_Belgrano#Sinking) by the submarine HMS Conqueror. This sinking killed a large number of conscripted Argentinian soldiers, and has been a matter of considerable controversy in the intervening years since.

The parliamentary opposition was certainly allowed its view, but undoubtedly, some protesters were arrested during demonstrations. Of course, the authorities viewpoint is that they were arrested for their actions rather than their views or their peaceful expression of them.

Comment: Not particularly significant at the time, but worth mentioning in the UK's current political context is that Labour leader Jeremy Corbyn opposed the war, calling it a 'Tory plot' (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_positions_of_Jeremy_Corbyn#Falklands )

Answer (score 19):

Sinn Féin (and therefore presumably the IRA) [took the Argentinian side](https://www.boards.ie/b/thread/2056599097) in the Falklands War, although it was not a major policy and seems to have been mostly an anti-British and anti-colonial policy, rather than strong support for Argentina. Sinn Féin are an Irish Republican group and the political wing of the IRA, then a terrorist organisation. Sinn Féin are active in Northern Ireland, part of the UK.

So Sinn Féin gives an example of a group that not only opposed the war, but supported the "other side". Across the border, Fianna Fáil also supported the Argentinian side. At the time, Sinn Féin were getting about 10% support in Northern Ireland.

Members of Sinn Féin were not arrested for their support for Argentina. However IRA member were arrested (as the IRA was a proscribed organisation)

Comment: Fianna Fáil are an Irish party, nothing to do with the UK.

Comment: I know. That is what "across the border" means.  Just giving some context. There was not uniform support for the UK among her neighbours.

Comment: The question quite clearly specifies UK support. Not her neighbours.

Comment: @mickburkejnr: Sinn Fein are a UK party, active in Northern Ireland, but as an Irish Republican party the matching position of the political parties in Eire is relevant to the answer.

Comment: @mickburkejnr Members of Sinn Fein are elected to the House of Commons.

Comment: But Sinn Fein have never sat or taken their seats in parliament, so in reality while they are elected they do not vote.